# Prove that $A' ∪ B' ∪ (A ∩ B ∩ C')$ is equivalent to $A' ∪ B' ∪ C'$ by algebraic laws

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, algebraic-logic

I know $A' ∪ B' ∪ (A ∩ B ∩ C')$ is equivalent to $A' ∪ B' ∪ C'$ by drawing Venn diagram.

But I can't successfully prove by algebraic laws.

Here is what I've tried:

$$A' ∪ B' ∪ (A ∩ B ∩ C')$$
$$= A' ∪ [(B' ∪ A) ∩ (B' ∪ B) ∩ (B' ∪ C')] \quad\text{distributive laws}$$
$$= A' ∪ [(B' ∪ A) ∩ T ∩ (B' ∪ C')]   \quad\text{negation laws} $$
$$= A' ∪ [(B' ∪ A) ∩ (B' ∪ C')]    \quad\text{identity laws} $$

And then, I can't proceed to $A' ∪ B' ∪ C'$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need to apply the distributive law once.
$$\begin{array}{rl}
A'\cup B'\cup\left(A\cap B \cap C'\right) = & (A'\cup B')\cup\left[(A\cap B) \cap C'\right] \mbox{ associativity }\\
= & [(A'\cup B')\cup(A\cap B)] \cap (A'\cup B'\cup
C')\mbox{ distributivity }\\
= & A'\cup B'\cup
C' \mbox{ negation of intersection}
 \end{array}$$